# File path completion relative to the current file directory

Tags: node.js, vim, macvim

Is it possible to have file path completion relative to the current file directory ?
To be able to search a file (like with command-t or ctrlP) and insert the relative path.

This is mainly for NodeJS/Component development, to require other modules of my project.

(I found this as an example for Sublime Text https://github.com/jfromaniello/sublime-node-require)

Thanks

**Edit:**

I add an example to illustrate my question:

```
.
|-- models
|   `-- user.js
`-- views
    `-- home
        `-- index.js
```

I'm working on the file `views/home/index.js` and I want to require the `models/user.js` into `views/home/index.js`

```
var userModel = require('../../models/user');
```

Is there a way in Vim to get the path of `models/user.js` relative to `views/home/index.js` (here in my example =`'../../models/user'`).

Comment: Please provide an example. Verbal descriptions without examples can be unclear and open to interpretation.

Comment: So, something like <C-x><C-f>, only with a fuzzy search?

Answer (score 4):

Filename-completion is always done from the working directory.

If you always want to do things relative to the current file, you can add

```
set autochdir
```

to your `~/.vimrc`.

You can change the working directory for the current window with

```
:lcd %:p:h
```

See `:help 'autochdir'`, `:help :lcd` and `:help filename-modifiers`.